# Comparing reading directly using pyspark vs pandas and then converting to spark dataframe. Warning - task of very large size in second approach

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running pyspark code on my local machine and trying to understand how to get rid of pyspark warning-
`23/10/02 11:31:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 36 contains a task of very large size (2886 KiB). The maximum recommended task size is 1000 KiB.`

So I did a comparing test:
CASE I:
Code:

```
scada = spark.read.csv('../processed/scada_data.csv')
scada.count()
```

Output:
`337777`

CASE II:
Code:

```
test = pd.read_csv('../processed/scada_data.csv')
spark_scada = spark.createDataFrame(test)
spark_scada.count()
```

Output:

```
23/10/02 11:31:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 36 contains a task of very large size (2886 KiB). The maximum recommended task size is 1000 KiB.
337776
```

Interestingly, I do not get the warning when directly reading the csv using pyspark. But if I read it using pandas and then convert it to a spark dataframe, I get the warning. So, what can I do when reading csv through pandas and then convert to spark dataframe to get rid of the warning, the same way there is no warning when reading directly through pyspark?

I read multiple posts suggesting using repartition or parallelize functions. When I try the repartition function the large size value does not change at all. And I haven't tried parallelize because I do not want the dataframe to convert into RDD.